# How I can convert NFC tag payload to URL using CoreNFC?

Tags: ios, swift, core-nfc

I am trying to write a function for converting NFC tag payload data to a URL to open it in safari but it's not opening due to some reason as it fails to convert it into URL. My code is here:

```
 func readerSession(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession, didDetectNDEFs messages: [NFCNDEFMessage]) {
    var result = ""
      for payload in messages[0].records{
          print("-> \(payload)") //Prints the Entire NFC Payload on the Tag.
        result += String.init(data: payload.payload, encoding: .utf16) ?? "Format not supported"
      }
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        guard let url = URL(string: result) else { return }
        UIApplication.shared.open(url)

      }
}
```

Comment: What does `String.init(data: payload.payload, encoding: .utf16)` produce?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc/nfcndefpayload/3153117-wellknowntypeuripayload Also, could you check the `typeNameFormat` ? `let urls = messages[0].records.flatMap{ $0.wellKnownTypeURIPayload };
urls.forEach{ print("anUrl: \($0.absoluteString)" }` Also, appending the urls like that? In chunk?

Answer (score 1):

You need to decode the payload, because it is encoded as described in NFC Forum Technical specification (for example NFCForum-TS-NDEF_1.0.pdf, grab it where it is possible, but in the "white direction" - this document needs to be purchased)

NDEF is complex format, and for correct decoding, you need to comply to all features (no need to implement all of them, but you need to be ready to understand all data which appear inside the payload).

In short, for decode for URL type, you need to react on two types of payload (my code in Objective-C, but it can be rewritten in Swift):

```
NSDictionary *urlData; // <- Desired URL placed here
NSString *payloadType = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:payload.type encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
if ([@"Sp" isEqualToString:payloadType]) {
    urlData = [NDEFProcessor parseSmartPoster:payload.payload];
} else if ([@"U" isEqualToString:payloadType]) {
    urlData = [NDEFProcessor parseUriPrimitive:payload.payload];
}
```

where `NDEFProcessor` functions is:

```
+ (NSString *) uriPrefixForType: (uint8_t) type {
    switch (type) {
        default: return @"";
        case 0x01: return @"http://www.";
        case 0x02: return @"https://www.";
        case 0x03: return @"http://";
        case 0x04: return @"https://";
        case 0x05: return @"tel:";
        case 0x06: return @"mailto:";
    }
}
+ (NSDictionary *) parseUriPrimitive:(NSData *) payload {
    NSMutableDictionary *result = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    int schemeType = ((uint8_t *) payload.bytes) [0];
    NSString *uriRaw = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:payload.bytes  + 1 length:payload.length - 1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *proto = [NDEFProcessor uriPrefixForType:schemeType];
    [result setObject: proto
            forKey: @"PROTO"];
    [result setObject: uriRaw
            forKey: @"RAW"];
    [result setObject: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", proto, uriRaw]
            forKey: @"URI"];
    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:result];
}

+ (NSDictionary *) parseSmartPoster:(NSData *) payload {
    NSMutableDictionary *result = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    int pos = 0;
    uint8_t recordHeader;
    do {
        recordHeader = ((uint8_t *) payload.bytes)[pos];
        uint8_t recordLength = ((uint8_t *) payload.bytes)[pos + 2];
        uint8_t recordType = ((uint8_t *) payload.bytes) [pos + 3];
        if (recordType == 0x55) {
            // URI
            NSDictionary *uriDictionary = [self parseUriPrimitive:[payload subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(pos + 4, recordLength)]];
            if (uriDictionary != nil) {
                [result addEntriesFromDictionary:uriDictionary];
            }
        }
    pos = pos + recordLength + 4;
    } while ((pos < payload.length) || ((recordHeader & (1 << 6)) != 0x40));
    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:result];
}
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc/nfcndefpayload/3153117-wellknowntypeuripayload isn't enough for most of your cases?

Comment: @Larme, in a case of Smart Poster record, the record present in a two "sub-records": text+Uri. In this case you need to "decompile" complex Sp record in a two primitive Uri+Text. I am not sure about Apple - can it handle complex records or not.